# Exit shell script containing indefinitely running java program

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, autosys

I have an `autosys` job. In the `autosys` job I am executing a `shell` script. Shell script executes **indefinitely** running java program. Say infinite `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/ksh

function abc() {
    java DemoJavaProgram
    RESULT=$?
    if[ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
        exit 0;
    else
        exit 1;
}
abc | tee output.file
```

Above shell script is not returning anything instead it is stuck at running java program. Due to this `autosys` job status is `RUNNING`

I tried running above command in the background with `&` I had no success. I tried running an entire shell script in the background, even in this case also I had no success.

is there any way to exit from such script.

**[tl;dr] I want to start the java program and exit the script**

Comment: You're checking the exit status code of a java program that never exits? Do you just want to start the java program in the background and exit the script?

Comment: What's your objective of using `return 0` and `return 1` in the script?

Comment: With this program, it's obvious that your Autosys job will continue running, because your code is just checking the exit status(0) of the java program which was started successfully and your `if` condition is just evaluating to to `true` all the time.

Comment: @Haxiel You got me right. I want to start the java program and exit the script. I don't mind removing `if-else` block from the code.

Comment: @User123 I don't mind removing `remove` statements, what I want to achieve above is, execute the java command and exit the shell script with Autosys job status as `SUCCESS`

Comment: So please update your question with these clarifications. _Make it easy for us to help you._

Comment: Why you use the shell script to start the java program? Why you do not start the java program directly without a shell script? e.g. `java DemoJavaProgram >output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with autosys itself, but you can start a long-running command in the background like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
nohup java DemoJavaProgram 1> output.file 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

The `nohup` command allows the `java` command to survive hangup signals. The input and output are then redirected. The `&` operator at the end forces the command to run in the background.

Do note that you will not be able to depend upon the exit status code here. If the `java` command fails to start for some reason, it will write the error message to the output file and exit.

Comment: This solution is not working. Script is still running in the background. I check with `ps -aux` and script is not exiting.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Can you elaborate? If I put this command inside a script, say `test.sh` and run `./test.sh`, I get the intended result. The command inside the script continues running, while the script itself does not. How does your approach differ?

Comment: What happens if you replace the java with, for example, `ls`?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare My example syntax was previously not valid for a ksh environment. Sorry about that. Can you take a look at the edit and see if it works for you now?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor There was previously an error in my answer, which I have now corrected. The `ls` command will also work as expected with this approach (i.e. contents of the directory will be written to output.file).

Comment: @Haxiel, sorry that comment was not for you. It is for the OP. I think that if your answer does not work, then answering the question I pose in the comment, may find the problem (so long at they do the experiment for real, not in their head).

Comment: @Haxiel I debugged the script, as it seems `| tee output.file` is creating one more process. is there any way to handle such redirection.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare If you only want to collect the output into a file, you don't need to use `tee`. The script from my answer already does that. You'll get the output of the java program inside 'output.file'. Instead of combining the two scripts, please try running the script from my answer as-is and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement, you need to replace `return` functions with `exit`:

Can you try below and check:

```
#!/bin/ksh
java DemoJavaProgram
RESULT=$?
if [ "$RESULT" -eq 0 ]
 then
    echo "SUCCESS"
exit 1
else 
echo "FAILURE"
fi
```

Comment: what the point in `echo SUCCESS`.  The script will keep running as `DemoJavaProgram` runs for an indefinite period of time. besides that Autosys looks for the script to exit gracefully.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare: Yes, you can remove the `echo SUCCESS` part from the script, i just added it for the descriptive purpose, also it'll neither affect your requirement of exiting the script on the successful starting of the java program nor your `Autosys` job. Your Autosys job will exit gracefully and if you think of configuring the log path/name for this Autosys job, then this `echo` part (you can include the description as per your convenience)will come as handy to you or to your team ,just to validate that the script started without any issue.

Comment: Solution is not working, script is still running in the background, `exit 1` is not terminating the script process. I checked using `ps -aux | grep scriptName.ksh`. Autosys job status is also `RUNNING`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `autosys` either, but one hack that can be used to start long-running programs from udev rules or from a user session (and work around systemd killing background jobs despite `nohup`) is using the the `at(1)` command.

```
echo your_cmd | at now
```

Any output from the `your_cmd` will be mailed to the user running it. If you don't like that, you can use redirects:

```
echo 'your_cmd >/dev/null 2>/path/to/errorlog' | at now
```

The `at` from linux also has a non-standard `-M` option for that:

```
echo 'your_cmd' | at -M now # ignore any output
```

Unfortunately, there's no option to shut up `at`'s informational messages, so you'll have to filter them out yourself:

```
#! /bin/sh
function run_with_at(){
    echo "$@" | at now 2>&1 |
        egrep >&2 -v '^warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh$|^job [0-9]+ at'
}
run_with_at 'java DemoJavaProgram >/dev/null' # any stderr output will still be mailed to the user
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control a process by checking its result. The  link describes how to control the run time, and do various checks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your start script, you do not need it. Simple start your java program with redirection like this.

`java DemoJavaProgram >output.txt`

Every output of your Java program `System.out.print*` will occur in the output.txt file. If you need also the `System.err.print*` in your output.txt, append also `2>&1` or if you would like to have the error output in an extra file add `2>failure.txt` or if you really do not need the error output add `2>/dev/null`

If you need to start it in background, append `&`.

If you start it from an other system, use nohup as mentioned by @Haxiel.

`nohup java DemoJavaProgram 1> output.file 2>&1 </dev/null &`

If you need to take a look in the output.txt after a while:
`tail -f output.txt` will show last 10 lines of output.txt and continued.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit puzzling to me, not in the least because of the pipe (to `tee`) that you apparently wish to use. To maintain this functionality, you could use the following script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
tee output.file < <( java DemoJavaProgram ) &
```

That's it. The script will terminate, the java program will continue to run in the background, and data output by the java program on stdout will be copied to both stdout and `output.file`.

I note that simply running `ps -aux | grep scriptName.ksh` may mislead you into believing that the script is still running, since the process substitution `<(...)` is likely run in/from a subshell process that bears the name of the original script, but is actually a child of `tee`. The parent, i.e. the above script, will have died, as should be apparent from the PPID (i.e. Parent PID) value that you can inspect with, for instance, `ps -o pid,ppid,tty,comm -H`.